# Ionic1 Edit Record & Populate Fields

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic1 application which has a function which allows the user to edit a record. For example, change a contact from prospect to customer.

When I click edit on the prospect, this loads a view for editing the prospect.

My application then shows a form and populates the fields with the prospect data after a $http.get request allowing the user to amend / update the prospect as required.

My problem, when clicking edit only some of the dropdown lists are populating.

**My controller for editing a prospect**

```
.controller('prospectCtrlEdit', function($scope, $http,  $state, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, prospects, customers) {

  $ionicLoading.show();

  $http.get('URL_API_END_POINT/' + $stateParams.customer + '/edit?token=' + localStorage.getItem("token")).then(function(successResponse){

    $scope.return = successResponse;
    $scope.prospect = $scope.return.data.data.prospect;

    $ionicLoading.hide();

  }, function(errorRepsonse){
     $scope.error = errorRepsonse;
     $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     $ionicLoading.hide();

  });

});
```

**My form**

```
<div class="list">
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Type
    </div>
    <select ng-model="prospect.client_type">
      <option value="2">Prospect</option>
      <option value="1">Customer</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <div class="input-label">
    Title
  </div>
  <select ng-model="prospect.title">
    <option value="Mr and Mrs">Mr & Mrs</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First name" ng-model="prospect.first_name">
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" ng-model="prospect.last_name">
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="prospect.email">
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label">Mobile</span>
  <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="prospect.mobile">
</label>

<div class="item">
  <button class="button button-block" ng-click="updateProspect()">Update Profile</button>
</div>
</div>
```

For reference, I've included my response from the API which is what is being used to populate the form.

```
{
   "data":{
      "status":"success",
      "prospect":{
         "id":5887,
         "user_id":9,
         "title":"Mr and Mrs",
         "company":null,
         "first_name":"Peter",
         "last_name":"Prospect",
         "email":"",
         "mobile":"",
         "telephone":null,
         "addressline1":null,
         "addressline2":null,
         "addressline3":null,
         "addressline4":null,
         "lat":null,
         "long":null,
         "town":null,
         "postcode":null,
         "county":null,
         "country":null,
         "comments":null,
         "status":1,
         "created_at":"2017-07-12 20:52:48",
         "updated_at":"2017-07-12 20:52:48",
         "client_type":2,
         "prospect_converted":null
      }
   }
}
```

> To recap. When the edit prospect page loads the form is populated with
>   all the current data from the above $http.get() request. The user
>   updates the information as desired - the problem is dropdowns like
>   "Type" for determining the type either Customer or Prospect isn't auto
>   populating however the title is.

Comment: Did you verify that prospect contains the correct data while editing?

Comment: @Vivz yea, the form part fills i.e. first name, last name etc but the type doesn't?